# Force browser to download image file from external server in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, external

Images in my project are from an external server; I want to download them when click on download button or  tag, but open them in another page.

```
                @foreach($items as $item)
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 nopad image-gallery">
                    <a target="_blank" class="fancybox mediaReportItem persianNum downloadImg" rel="fancybox-button"
                       downloadpath="{{ $mediaAddress. '/' .$item->image->original_path }}" id="{{ $item->id }}"
                       href="{{ $mediaAddress. '/' .$item->image->original_path }}" title="{{ $item->title }}">
                        <img src="{{ $mediaAddress. '/' .$item->image->thumb_path }}" class="photoThumbnaill"
                             alt="{{ $item->title }}" download></a>
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

And download not work Because image is on external server.

```
response()->download($file);
```

Comment: hey can you share the $item array or obj whatever you are passing only two iteration will be fine for me to test the code

Answer (score 0):

Since you will need to set a header (because `a[download]` only works on same-origin URLs) you need to proxy the file i.e. create a route that returns the file contents.

A simple implementation:

```
return response(file_get_contents($url), 200, [
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="filename.png"',
]);
```